# Controlling graduated classification of vector layer

Tags: qgis

I have a map layer of zip codes, I would like to display the point symbol one color if there is no data (data type is number so that would be 0). If I have a number 1-50 the zip code should be a different symbol.

QGIS seems to always automatically force the number in the low range into the high number of the preceding value range so 0-0 and 1-50 become 0-1 1-50 thus any zip code with just one as the value will not display as a zip with a value... conversely 0-0 0-50 shows all zip code as having a value.

Is there a way to set the graduate style with ranges 0-0 and 1-50?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch your layer to Rule-based styling. Create a new rule, and under Filter type `"zip_code_field" = 0`. Make sure this rule is at the top of the list so that it is symbolized first.

If there are truly no data for some features, you may want to make a rule specifying `zip_code_field" IS NULL`, as an empty attribute is not necessarily assumed zero in a numeric field.

Comment: A quick way to set up the rules is to first set the up the styling as categorized (as you were already doing), then convert to rule-based. The rules will be automatically generated, and you can manually edit the range values.

Comment: Hey, I did this feature! Nice to see that other people find it useful!